# How to implement UIScrollView dropdown or pullup go back like this?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, drop-down-menu

I have two views `RootViewController` and `DetailViewController`, when I am in `DetailViewController`, I want to back `RootViewController`

1. Click back button
2. Dropdown or pullup back (I want)

[image: http://wangliang.me/images/dropdown-back.png]

[image: http://wangliang.me/images/pullup-back.png]

I don't konw how to implement.

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking a look at this example code: [Pull To Refresh](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh). It's for refreshing but you can easily adapt it for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use NavigationController to do the job for you. There are lots of tutorial available to teach you how to create that.

To navigate back when you pull call popviewcontroller.

Comment: Thanks, I know that, but I want to know how to display that slide view when scrollview dropdown, some demo code or tutorials link?

Comment: @StevenWang. You can google for "custom sliders iphone". You will get many links.